# Java screen scraping, how to get respone from redirect post request

Tags: java, screen-scraping, jsoup

I just experimenting on data extraction thing with java, search in this forum and found that it was called screen scraping. i have looking for screen scraper library for java and found JSoup to parse the result.

My problem is the target website using post method when search form submitted, its not easy to re-produce it, also i check with developer tools in chrome that response code after submit action is 302 and redirect to some page and then redirect again to the result page.

please somebody give me a hint or point me to a tutorial how to do it with jsoup.
in my case i try to retrieve flight schedule from ai*ras*ia.*com

Answer (score 0):

in JSOUP there is function called .followRedirects(followRedirects) which gives you the option if you want to follow redirects or not by default it is set to "true".

and thse are the HTTP code that it allowes redirects for:

- 301 - HTTP_MOVED_PERM
- 302 - HTTP_MOVED_TEMP
- 303 - HTTP_SEE_OTHER